# how to download a .pdf file from mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I am using the following code to download a pdf file from mysql database. The code works perfectly with localhost, pdf gets downloaded. But now when the site is live, I can't download the file. It throws some characters like these on the screen..Úáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ ÿÄ.

My code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['download']))
{
$Tno2 = $_SESSION['Tno'];
$gotten = @mysql_query("select * from tenders where Tno = '$Tno2'");
$row1 = @mysql_fetch_assoc($gotten);
$bytes = $row1[file];
if (empty($bytes))
  {
    echo "<b>Tender document not available for this tender.</b>";
  }
else
  {
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="Tenderdoc.pdf"');
    print $bytes;
  }
 }
```

Please suggest the required changes in my code or anything which i might be missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your question. Are you stroing URL of pdf in database or storing as bytes in database?

If you are storing as URL, Check whether you are giving valid path

Comment: pdf is stored in the mysql db in the form of blob (datatype: medium blob)